# Are all Vectors of a Basis Orthogonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Assuming we have a basis for a set $\mathbb{R}^n$, would any set of linearly independent vectors that form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$ also be orthogonal to each other?

Take the trivial case of $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$. Now any set of linear independent vectors would be a scalar multiple of these two vectors that form a Basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$ hence they have to be orthogonal. Right?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No. The set $\beta=\{(1,0),(1,1)\}$ forms a basis for $\Bbb R^2$ but is not an orthogonal basis. This is why we have Gram-Schmidt!

More general, the set $\beta=\{e_1,e_2,\dotsc,e_{n-1},e_1+\dotsb+e_n\}$ forms a non-orthogonal basis for $\Bbb R^n$.

To acknowledge the conversation in the comments, it is true that orthogonality of a set of vectors implies linear independence. Indeed, suppose $\{v_1,\dotsc,v_k\}$ is an orthogonal set of nonzero vectors and
$$
\lambda_1 v_1+\dotsb+\lambda_k v_k=\mathbf 0\tag{1}
$$
Then applying $\langle-,v_j\rangle$ to (1) gives $\lambda_j\langle v_j,v_j\rangle=0$ so that $\lambda_j=0$ for $1\leq j\leq k$.

The examples provided in the first part of this answer show that the converse to this statement is not true.

Comment: but they are not linearly independence right? Can you also please explain Gram-Schmidt because I have trouble understanding from videos and my book?

Comment: Yes, $(1,0)$ and $(1,1)$ are linearly independent. Soliciting information on Gram-Schmidt might be better suited for a different question.

Comment: @μακακας to use _very_ imprecise terminology, for a vector $\in\mathbb{R}^n$ to be linearly independent only means that it must be "partly orthogonal" to the other vectors in the set - in other words, that it must have some component that is orthogonal to the other vectors, but it can also have components parallel to one or more of those other vectors. To be orthogonal means it cannot have any component parallel to any of the other vectors. So orthogonality is a more restrictive criterion than linear independence.

Comment: I am still confused about orthogonality but thanks anyways. I found a theorem that says An orthogonal set of non zero vectors in R^n is linearly independent so I guess it doesn't work the other way around?

Comment: @DavidZ your answer is amazing... It helped me visualize it and understood what I got wrong.

Comment: @BrianFitzpatrick please explain to me if I use gram-schmitd process.. which can orthogonalize any basis.. if the original basis is not orthogonal how can the transformed base and the original be equivalent?

Comment: @μακακας What do you mean by "equivalent"?

Comment: @BrianFitzpatrick the notion of equivalency that I have in my head when studying Linear Algebra is that they are interchangeable, just like a matrix (Ax=0) is the "same" as before after a row operation.

Comment: @μακακας What would it mean for two different bases to be "interchangeable"?

Comment: Perhaps @μακακας is talking about how, when you use a matrix $A$ to represent the system of linear equations $Ax=0$, adding a multiple of one row of $A$ to another row (a "row operation") results in another system of equations $Bx=0$ that is satisfied by $y$ iff $Ay=0$. I'm not sure how that's supposed to relate to bases, though. (My _guess_: μακακας thinks adding a multiple of one basis vector to another vector in the same basis results in an "equivalent" basis, and also believes that any basis equivalent to an orthogonal basis must also be orthogonal. μακακας can you confirm/deny?)

Answer (score 8):

In general: No! Any vectors ${\bf u} = (u_1,u_2,u_3)$, ${\bf v} = (v_1,v_2,v_3)$ and ${\bf w} = (w_1,w_2,w_3)$ will span $\mathbb{R}^3$ if, and only if, the following determinant is non-zero:
$$\left|\begin{array}{ccc} u_1 & v_1 & w_1 \\
  u_2 & v_2 & w_2 \\
  u_3 & v_3 & w_3 \end{array}\right| \neq 0$$
This is equivalent to the *single* polynomial condition
$$u_1(v_2w_3-w_2v_3) - v_1(u_2v_3 - w_2u_3) + w_1(u_2v_3-v_2u_3) \neq 0$$

For a set of non-zero vectors to be orthogonal, we need them all to be at right angles:

$$\langle {\bf u}, {\bf v}\rangle = \langle {\bf u}, {\bf w}\rangle = \langle {\bf v}, {\bf w}\rangle =0$$
For this to happen, we need three *simultaneous* polynomial conditions:

\begin{eqnarray*}
u_1v_1 + u_2v_2 + u_3v_3 &=& 0 \\ \\
u_1w_1 + u_2w_2 + u_3w_3 &=& 0 \\ \\
v_1w_1 + v_2w_2 + v_3w_3 &=& 0 
\end{eqnarray*}

There are many sets of linearly independent vectors $\{{\bf u},{\bf v},{\bf w}\}$ which are not orthogonal.

Answer (score 4):

Nope. $(1,1)$ and $(1,0)$ form a basis of $\mathbb R^2$.